# Find an infinite power series of the form an$z^n$ with radius of convergence 1 that converges for z such that |z|=1 except when z = z1, z2, ...zm.

Tags: power-series

Find an infinite power series of the form $\sum_n a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence 1 that converges for every $z$ such that $|z|=1$ except when $z = z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m$ where $z_1$, $z_2,\ldots, z_m$ are complex numbers with modulus 1.

Comment: Do you know an example of power series of radius of convergence 1 which converges for all $z$ s.t. $|z| = 1$, except for $z = 1$?

Comment: Yep, $(z^n)/n$ Do I have to consider the complex number in exponential form? Or in terms of sin and cos?

Comment: Well, either will do. But it is probably more simple to use it in exponential form. Now, the only thing you have to do is to modify the $\sum \frac{z^n}n$ example a bit to produce the example you're looking for. First step: how to make an example of a power series converging for all complex numbers of modulus 1 **except for** $z=z_1$?

Comment: Multiply the z by the conjugate of z1? so $(z1^*z)^n/n$?

Comment: Yes. So now you have power series $\sum \frac{(\overline{z_i} z)^n}{n}$, each only diverging on the point $z = z_i$. How to combine them so to get a power series diverging on all of these points?

Comment: I am not sure, you can't multiply by all the conjugates as still only one point will converge but you also can't have (z1* +z2*...+zn*)$z^n$ as this doesn't have a radius of convergence equal to 1.

Comment: No, what you have to do is to multiply all these power series. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Umm, I don't think I have come across it no. I guess it isn't as simple as multiplying the sums together??

Comment: The technical term is Cauchy Product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product ; basically, it is the same formula as the one you use to multiply two polynomials. If you do that to all your power series, you will get the example you're looking for.